# Parse Complex JSON to ASP.NET MVC 3 using jQuery

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have to post this javascript object to asp.net controller:

[image]

The model in server side is:

```
public class UserExperience
 {
     public class competences
     {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string level { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool isNew { get; set; }
        public bool isSaved { get; set; }
    }

    public long id { get; set; }
    public string startDate { get; set; }
    public string endDate { get; set; }
    public string projectName { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string customerIndustry { get; set; }
    public string jobTitle { get; set; }
    public string projectDescription { get; set; }
    public string responsabilities { get; set; }
    public List<competences> competence { get; set; }
    public List<int> deletedCompetences { get; set; }
    public bool isNew { get; set; }
    public bool isSaved { get; set; }

}
```

I tried to send the json like this:

```
$.ajax("/candidate/saveUserExperience", {
        data : JSON.stringify({ue: is.Candidate.BO.userExperience[id]}),
        //dataType: "text",
        contentType : "application/json",
        type : 'POST'
    })
```

And this is the controller where I receive it:

```
public JsonResult saveUserExperience(UserExperience ue)
    {
            bool success;

        success = true;

            return Json(new { success, ue }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And I receive a null object.

I tried to do with:

```
 UserExperience userExperience = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<UserExperience>(ue);
```

and I do not receive the competence subclass object.

Is there a solution to this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll surely need to use toDictionnary plugin for posting more complex model to asp.net. The plugin is explained here http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to pass is.Candidate.BO.userExperience[id] when you expect UserExperience object? Just write **data: ue** in ajax call parameters,

Comment: You are still passing the id instead of the full object as part of your ajax data call. As @pele said, you need to pass data: eu for the code to send the full object (i.e eu)